# C++: How can a member object of a class tell this class, if a variable of this member object changes (callback seems not to work)

Tags: c++, class, callback

My question in code:

I have a class A, which has a private member b of class B, like:

```
class A 
{ 
public:
      A();
      ~A();
private:
      B b;
};

class B
{
public:
      B();
      ~B();
      int getMemberOfB() {return m_memberOfB;}
private:
      int m_memberOfB;
};
```

Is there any way to observe the `m_memberOfB` in an object of A, if `m_memberOfB` changes? (like signal & slot mechanism in qt) Because b is a member of class A, the callback may should also not work, does it? Acctually I want to get the current value of `m_memberOfB` in an object of A, if `m_memberOfB` is changed. Any idea ?   Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I'm new to callback. If callback can work, I want to set a member function of class A as a callback, which can be called by B. But in order to call the callback function, there should be an object of A, which can call the callback. How can I get an instance of A in b ? Or rather set the callback as global function?  Could anyone give me a small example ? Thanks very much !

Comment: Why a callback can´t work? B has a pointer to function (etc.), if not null then call it every time setB is called. In A´s constructor, set some function as callback of the B object.

Comment: Signals and slots are there for a reason. You have to provide a template with overloaded operators to get functionality and observer notification at the same time, and register callbacks to the instances of this template.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably want to make `B::m_memberOfB` a static; otherwise, you will have a different instance of it for every instance of a B class which would mean you would know when it changes because you would be changing it from your A object.

After that, you need to put the problem into context. There are loads of signalling mechanisms in C/C++, it all depends on what you are dealing with. 
For example, when you are dealing with threads,you could use mutexes and/or semaphores and for inter-process signalling you have pipes or signals.
You can even use message queues.

Let's assume you only have one thread (main) and you want to achieve what you just said - you would have to use polling, whether you manually check the value to see if it changed, or use a mutex that will be release only when the value changes is up to you, but you are still polling.